# Return a count from a given month as column

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a query to return a count (number of pagehits) from a given month as a column. I haven't been able to find an example that does exactly what I need.

For example:

```
Title | Path | Total | September | October | November |
-------------------------------------------------------
Home  | /    |   500 |       200 |     125 |      175 |
```

It doesn't have to be totally dynamic, as it will be a one-time operation to get some old statistics.

I hope you guys can help me out

**UPDATE:**

The structure of the table with the 'hits' is something like:

```
id | page | date
```

I am joining other tables for the path and title, but those are not relevent for this question

Comment: Please, post the rellevant tables structure

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled at the presentation layer/application level code.

Comment: I think what you want is a PIVOT TABLE: Look at here some examples: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: @jorge: the pivot table looks like something I need indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for year 2013:

```
SELECT 
    Page as Path,
    COUNT(*) as Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JAN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date)=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FEB,
    ....
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date)=12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DEC
    FROM HitsTable
    WHERE YEAR(Date)=2013
GROUP BY Page;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. Simple, fast & working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your table has columns called `Title`, `path` and `request_date`, then, your query could be:

```
 select Title, path,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv2
          where month(request_date)=2
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as January,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv1
          where month(request_date)=2
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as February,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv3
          where month(request_date)=3
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as April,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv5
          where month(request_date)=5
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as May,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv6
          where month(request_date)=6
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as June,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv7
          where month(request_date)=7
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as July,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv1
          where month(request_date)=1
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as January,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv8
          where month(request_date)=8
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as August,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv9
          where month(request_date)=9
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as September,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv10
          where month(request_date)=10
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as October,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv11
          where month(request_date)=11
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as November,
        (select count(*)
           from page_views as pv12
          where month(request_date)=12
            and pv1.Title = pv.Title
            and pv2.path = pv.path
        ) as December
  from (select distinct Title,path
          from page_views
       ) as pv
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want, I think is something called **PIVOT TABLE**. For your table structure I would og for:

```
select id, path, jan+feb+....+dec as total,
       jan, feb, ... dec
  from (
select
    id, path,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=3 then 1 else 0 end) as mar,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=4 then 1 else 0 end) as apr,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=5 then 1 else 0 end) as may,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=6 then 1 else 0 end) as jun,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=7 then 1 else 0 end) as jul,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=8 then 1 else 0 end) as aug,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=9 then 1 else 0 end) as sep,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=10 then 1 else 0 end) as oct,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=11 then 1 else 0 end) as nov,
    sum(case when extract(month from date)=12 then 1 else 0 end) as dec
from 
    yourtable
group by id, path ) as tb
```